# Why the result of numpy.random.normal(0,1,N) doesn't add up to 0?

Tags: python, numpy, random

Why the result of numpy.random.normal(0,1,N) doesn't add up to 0? The actual mean of the generated distribution is not 0. I think it is not due to discretization because the offset of the mean from 0 doesn't seem to get smaller as N grows. I did try Ns that really challenge my machine. What am I missing?

I'm using it to generate a random noise to add to a simulated signal. I rely on the fact that the sum of all the noisy signal will approach the sum of only the signal because all the random values should add up to 0. Instead I get sum of signal plus the offset in the mean times the number of points.

Comment: Why would it? It's random...

Answer (score 3):

Sampled mean is not always same as theoretical mean.
But, when the sample size becomes big, then the difference will be small.

See the code.

```
import numpy as np
print(np.random.normal(0, 1, 100).mean()) # 0.08
print(np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000).mean()) # -0.03
print(np.random.normal(0, 1, 10000).mean()) # -0.004
print(np.random.normal(0, 1, 100000).mean()) # 0.0014
```

Comment: It's interesting that input parameters are not taken seriously. N needs to be too large for the mean to get close to 0. Also, the sum of the generated array will always grow as N grows, because the offset in the mean doesn't decrease as fast as N grows, and I do need the sum. For example with N=1e9 the mean will be ~1e-6, I wouldn't call that small. Note that such a call will generate an array that will take 8GB of memory!
Anyway, it's obvious how to work around this and I guess requiring exact mean goes against the requirement for randomness and vice versa. Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine some simple cases:

- N=1: almost no chance of getting exactly zero, once in a while you'll be near zero.
- N=2: whatever you get for the first number, better hope you get exactly the inverse for the second number.  Won't usually happen, wouldn't be random if it did.
- N=3: once you get the first two, now you need a specific value for the third number to cancel out the first two.  Good luck with that!

I think you see where this is going.  If you need a specific sum, you need to enforce it by reducing the randomness of at least one of the values.

Answer (score 0):

The theory says that the standard deviation of the mean of a normal sample is equal to sigma/sqrt(n) where n is the size of the sample and sigma the standard deviation of the normal distribution. So as @Gilseung said is his answer the mean get closer to 0 when the size of the sample increases.